# Web Service Proxy Generator In PHP Environment

Tags: php, web-services, visual-studio, webservice-client, phpstorm

In Visual Studio when we want to consume a web service, we simply add **Service Reference**, then simply copy and paste web service address to address field and click Go !

[image]

With help of Visual Studio IDE (or svcutil.exe ) we simply can use generated proxy classes for web service.

something like:

```
TopUpServiceClient client = new TopUpServiceClient();

TopUpRequest request = new TopUpRequest();
request.MerchantId = 100;
request.ReferenceId = 1001;
request.ServiceType = ServiceType.Prepaid;

TopUpResponse response = client.TopUp(request);
```

We Have a Customer that want to use our service with php, but he have lots of problems with creating and working with Soap Objects and Parsing WSDL and Data Contract Objects.

I have test his php scripts and debug it with fiddler, The Envelope that passed to our system is totally incorrect. ( he use SoapClient and NuSoap with no Luck !)

By the way,
**my question :**
Is There any Web Service Proxy Generator like what we have in Visual Studio In **PHP** World? Any IDE? PhpStorm, NetBeans, Eclips? Or any tools that can help us?

I want to send him some thing like our generated proxy environment, that he can use it easily!

Comment: I'm missing the question here. What kind of problems does your client have? Just `lots of problems` doesn't really clarify much.

Comment: Simply, He Cant Use Our web service :). He Passed Invalid Params to our method that don't compatible with WSDL definitions.

Comment: Uhm, as long as you provide the WSDL, PHP's [`SoapClient`](http://php.net/SoapClient) is just able to deal with that in a simple fashion.

Comment: Actualy we send them Flat file Wsdl. But they cant use the service! I think they have soap knowldge problem:). Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it.
A simple,tiny,useful Soap Proxy Generator.

"Soap Proxy" developed by "Przemek Berezowski"

you can download it from [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6781-PHP-Generate-code-to-access-SOAP-services-from-an-WSDL.html).

There are some other tools and script out there, but this little thing help me a lot!

Comment: How do you call the generated proxy in your php code?